# Testing code which checks for instances of ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby, database, testing, activerecord

I am testing for instances of ActiveRecord::Base in a gem I have written. This makes testing without a database very difficult as my test objects must be of class ActiveRecord::Base which throw the error ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished when a connection isn't present

The conditional in question contains the following:

```
object.instance_of? ActiveRecord::Base
```

How can I test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking forward to something like this: [Fake an active record model without db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586813/fake-an-active-record-model-without-db).

But why don't you setup a real test DB for it?

Comment: This worked well thanks. I want to avoid using a real database as it will slow down my tests and add an additional point of failure.